# invalid id declaration in kv file

Tags: python, kivy

i would like to follow this tutorial : [Kivy Design Language](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4QCoS-hj-s&list=PLCC34OHNcOtpz7PJQ7Tv7hqFBP_xDDjqg&index=5)
and  according this tutorial i have created following code and corresponding.kv file :

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
class MyGridLayout(Widget):
    Name =ObjectProperty(None)
    Profession = ObjectProperty(None)
    Year_of_Experience = ObjectProperty(None)
    def press(self):
        name =self.Name.text
        profession =self.Profession.text
        year_of_experience =self.Year_of_Experience.text
        # self.add_widget(Label(text=f'hello {name},your profession is {profession}'
        #                            f'and you have {year_of_experience} years of experience',
        #                       font_size=20))
        self.Name.text =""
        self.Profession.text =""
        self.Year_of_Experience.text =""


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return  MyGridLayout()

if __name__ =="__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

here is corresponding .kv file content :

```
``<MyGridLayout>
     Name:Name
     Profession:Profession
     Year_of_Experience:Year_of_Experience
     GridLayout:
          cols:1
          size:root.width,root.height
          GridLayout:
               cols:2
               Label:
                    text:"Name"
               TextInput:
                    id:Name
                    multiline:False
               Label:
                    text:"Profession"
               TextInput:
                    id:Profession
                    multiline:False
               Label:
                    text:"Year_of_Experience"
               TextInput:
                    id:Year_of_Experience
                    multiline:False
          Button:
               text:"Submit"
               font_size:32
               on_press:root.press()`
```

`
but when i am running the code, i am getting error at this line :

```
` kivy.lang.parser.ParserException: Parser: File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Data_Science\my.kv", line 2:
 ...
       1:<MyGridLayout>
 >>    2:     Name:Name
       3:     Profession:Profession
       4:     Year_of_Experience:Year_of_Experience
 ...
 Invalid data after declaration`
```

this guy's video  is  two years, so maybe some  changes has been done in declaration format or i am mixing something?please give me  a hint

Answer (score 1):

i have figure out solution  and i was surprised that  reason of the error was big letters, for instance Name,Profession ,etc, here is simple solution :

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
# Builder.load_file("my.kv")
class MyGridLayout(Widget):
    name =ObjectProperty(None)
    profession = ObjectProperty(None)
    year_of_Experience = ObjectProperty(None)
    def press(self):
        name =self.name.text
        profession =self.profession.text
        year_of_experience =self.year_of_Experience.text
        self.add_widget(Label(text=f'hello {name},your profession is {profession}'
                                   f'and you have {year_of_experience} years of experience',
                              font_size=10))
        self.name.text =""
        self.profession.text =""
        self.year_of_Experience.text =""


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return  MyGridLayout()

if __name__ =="__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

here is corresponding  kv file:

```
<MyGridLayout>
     name:name
     profession:profession
     year_of_Experience:year_of_Experience
     GridLayout:
          cols:1
          size:root.width,root.height
          GridLayout:
               cols:2
               Label:
                    text:"Name"
               TextInput:
                    id:name
                    multiline:False
               Label:
                    text:"Profession"
               TextInput:
                    id:profession
                    multiline:False
               Label:
                    text:"Year_of_Experience"
               TextInput:
                    id:year_of_Experience
                    multiline:False
          Button:
               text:"Submit"
               font_size:32
               background_normal:''
               background_color:(1,0,0,1)
               on_press:root.press()
```

it is still unknown for me why it is so, but i will remember this fact for future